# Comparing two columns of two dataframes (logical operators)

Tags: r, compare, logical-operators

I would like to compare two columns simultaneously. My data looks like this:

```
a <- data.frame("a1" = c(1,1,1,3,4), "a2" = c(2,1,2,1,2))
b <- data.frame("b1" = c(1,1,3,1,3), "b2" = c(2,2,1,2,1))
cbind(a, b)
#   a1 a2 b1 b2
# 1  1  2  1  2
# 2  1  1  1  2
# 3  1  2  3  1
# 4  3  1  1  2
# 5  4  2  3  1
```

I would like to identify all rows of a where `a1` is not in `b1` **or** where `a1` is in `b1` **but** `a2` for the special `a1` is not in `b2` for the special `b2`. So the second question is: When `a1` is in `b1` is then `a2` for this row for `a1` also in `b2` for this row for `b1`.

Example for line 2: I am checking, if `a1 = 1` is anywhere in `b1 = c(1,1,3,1,3)`. It is, so I want to check if `a2 = 1` in line 2 (where `a1 = 1`) is anywhere in `b2` where `b1 = a1 = 1`, so here `b2 = c(2, 2, 2)`. For line 2 `a2 = 1` is not in `b2 = c(2, 2, 2)`, so the result should show me this line.

The first question is easy to answer with the following code:

```
a[which(!(a$a1 %in% b$b1)), ]
#   a1 a2
# 5  4  2
```

But I can't fix the second problem. Maybe I am working in a wrong way with the logical operators. My result should look like this:

```
  a1 a2
2  1  1
4  4  2
```

Comment: It cannot work with `%in%` operator. Using it, you search in all vectors, without order. See for example the result of `c(1,2,3) %in% c(3,1,2)`.

Comment: it is not clear if you want to do it "row-wise" or globally. But as you stated it, all `a$a2` are in `b$b2` so your "or" condition is always `FALSE`

Comment: @Pascal The result of your minimal example is `TRUE TRUE TRUE` - and that is what I want.

Comment: @CathG I want to do it globally.

Comment: So, your code is returning what you asked. All `a2` exist in `b2`. Then `(a$a1 %in% b$b1 & !(a$a2 %in% b$b2))` returns all `FALSE`.

Comment: But the desired result described in the question is wrong. It is a contradiction to the logic of the algorithm.

Comment: Hm okay, you're right. That was my fault, maybe I verbalized it wrong. I would like to identify the rows where `a1` is in `a2` AND `a2` is not in `b2` for this special `a1` and I don't know how to do this. Maybe in other words. How can I identify row 2 from `a` with `1 1`?

Comment: @jogo So how I can get to my desired output?

Comment: what is the logic behind your desire? Please edit your question!  Following  your last comment on the logic `subset(a, (a1 %in% a2) & !(a2 %in% b$b2))` gives 0 rows.

Comment: I still don't follow you, when a1==1, b2 can equal 1 or 2 so a2==1 is in b2... to me, the desire output should be the 2 last rows of a (what you get with `a[sapply(seq(nrow(a)), function(i){!(a$a1[i] %in% b$b1) | !(a$a2[i]  %in% b$b2[a$a1==a$a1[i]])}), ]` )

Comment: Tried to explain my question better with an explicit example (see above). Sorry for the misunderstanding or not explicit verbalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the explanation in your edit, you want the rows where either the specific `a1` from `a` is not in `b1` from `b` or where the specific `a1` from `a` **is equal to** `b1` of the same row in `b` and `a2` from `a` is not among the values of `b2` from `b` of the rows for which `b1` equals the value of the specific `a1`.

In R, you can write this like that:

```
cond <- sapply(seq(nrow(a)), # check each row, one by one
               function (i){
                   !(a$a1[i] %in% b$b1) | # a1 of the specific row is not in b1 or
                   !(a$a2[i]  %in% b$b2[b$b1==a$a1[i]]) # a2 of the specific row is not in the values of b2 for which b1 equals a1 of the sepcific row
               })

a[cond, ]
#  a1 a2
#2  1  1
#5  4  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The function works for this example data, but for my real data I don't want to compare row by row, because the length of the rows of the two dataframes is not the same and the values for `a1` and `b1` don't have to appear in the same row. But that's my fault. I am learning from this question. Next time I have to descripe my problem more explicit and choose better example data. But I thought I choose them as simple as possible.

Comment: @user5514978, I've edited my answer, I think it should work now with your data (I cannot be sure as it is still a bit unclear to me what you really want)

Comment: Thanks really really much for your effort despite my bad explanation. It is working now. I've also found a (bad programmed) solution by myself with for-loops (see above).

Comment: @user5514978, glad to know it's working (with my solution you mean ?), although my solution includes a `for` loop ("hidden" behind `sapply`), you should avoid the multiple nested for loops, it yields to unefficiency

Comment: Yes, I meant your solution. Thanks again. Mine is also working, but (I know that) - you're right - it is unefficient. I am still learning programming with R.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer I improved the function test(). This version returns a dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame(a1=c(1,1,1,3,4), a2=c(2,1,2,1,2))
b <- data.frame(b1=c(1,1,3,1,3), b2=c(2,2,1,2,1))

test <- function (a, b) {
  R <- subset(a,!a1 %in% b$b1)

  I <- unique(a$a1[a$a1 %in% b$b1])
  for (i in I) {
    ai <- subset(a, a1 == i)
    bi <- subset(b, b1 == i)
    J <- unique(bi$b2)
    for (j in  unique(ai$a2)) if (! j %in% J) R <- rbind(subset(ai, a2==j), R)
  }
  R
}

test(a, b)
```

Comment: (same as above): Thanks for your answer! The function works for this example data, but for my real data I don't want to compare row by row, because the length of the rows of the two dataframes is not the same and the values for `a1` and `b1` don't have to appear in the same row. But that's my fault. I am learning from this question. Next time I have to descripe my problem more explicit and choose better example data. But I thought I choose them as simple as possible.

Comment: @user5514978 : I edited my answer based on your function.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not a nice solution, but it works with my data (unequal dimension of rows of the two datasets, not the same position of the values in the variables) - here with new example data, because I chose the first really bad.

```
a <- data.frame("a1" = c(1,1,1,3,4), "a2" = c(2,1,2,1,2))
b <- data.frame("b1" = c(1,3,1,1), "b2" = c(2,1,2,2))

test <- function (data1, data2) {

   for (i in unique(data1[data1$a1 %in% data2$b1, "a1"])) {
     temp_data1 <- data1[data1$a1 == i, c("a1", "a2")]
     temp_data2 <- data2[data2$b1 == i, c("b1", "b2")]

     for (j in unique(temp_data1$a2)) {
        test <- j %in% unique(temp_data2$b2)

       if (test == FALSE) {
          print(unique(temp_data1[temp_data1$a1 == i & temp_data1$a2 == j, ]))
       }
     }
   }

   for (k in unique(data1[which(!(data1$a1 %in% data2$b1)), "a1"])) {
     print(unique(data1[data1$a1 == k, c("a1", "a2")]))
   } 
 }

 test(a, b)
   a1 a2
 2  1  1
   a1 a2
 5  4  2
```